# Prevent a user from making changes to some columns in a MS SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, database-design, locking

I'd like to prevent a user from making changes to some columns in a MS SQL Server database. I cannot lock the column as READ ONLY as there will be changes made to that column. Let me explain as best as I can. Our ERP allows me to block certain fields/columns from users through their security tabs. Sounds great. However, if a person uses an ODBC or DSN connection they would be able to change data. As an example I don't want the user to be able to change costs or anything financial in a customer order table, but have no issue with him correcting incorrect addresses or shipping information. If I lock the table as READ ONLY then using the ERP would also block that column.
I hope i'm making sense here.
Thank you!

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2124/filtering-sql-server-columns-using-column-level-permissions/

Comment: i'm not sure there's enough information here.  in a normal situation, what tool would the users be using to modify data?

Answer (score 5):

You can revoke update on that column from a particular user:

```
REVOKE UPDATE ON OBJECT::Employees.Salary FROM theUser;
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017